# Orthogonal complement of a vector

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I have a matrix (in this case it's a vector but it could be a matrix) $\alpha$.

$$\alpha'=(-0.086877710\quad03767617)$$

In the paper describing the methodology I try to implement, this definition is given.

$$\alpha'\alpha^\bot=0$$

where $\alpha^\bot$ is the orthogonal complement of $\alpha'$ but I have no idea how to solve for $\alpha^\bot$

I am a programmer and not a mathematician so this is not really my terrain. I am working in Python by the way.

Comment: Rotate $\alpha$ ninety degrees in either direction.

Comment: I found a solution in Matlab. The function null(x, 'r') does exactly what I want https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html